# How do I find the source code for pythons os.openpty() function

Tags: python, cpython, tty, pty

I am trying to better understand how to write a linux terminal emulator in python. When looking at the module source code for [pty.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a094f0255eea1db58fb2cf14c200971e64ec36e/Lib/pty.py), it appears that `pty.openpty()` is a wrapper for `os.openpty()`.

```
def openpty():
"""openpty() -> (master_fd, slave_fd)
Open a pty master/slave pair, using os.openpty() if possible."""

try:
    return os.openpty()
except (AttributeError, OSError):
    pass
master_fd, slave_name = _open_terminal()
slave_fd = slave_open(slave_name)
return master_fd,
```

But when I look through the [os.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a094f0255eea1db58fb2cf14c200971e64ec36e/Lib/os.py#L1) module source code, there is no function named openpty(). In fact, I am unable to find the source code for os.openpty() anywhere in the cpython codebase. What am I missing?

Comment: The python source is at https://github.com/python. You'll find .py and .c files with the stuff you want.

Comment: It's not called`openpty` in the CPython source, and it's not implemented in Python. It's C code in [`posixmodule.c :: os_openpty_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c#L7272-L7369)

Comment: @wkl Thanks for this. For my future reference, how would I have walked the code from os.openpty() to os_openpty_impl. How does the code know that this mapping exists? Also, oddly, despite the keyword `os.openpty` clearly existing in the codebase, the search function in github does not return this file as a result.

Comment: As above, some built-in functions are actually implemented in C. Many of them are wrappers on Posix/libc functions and have the same name. On linux, `man openpty` will give you more information.

Comment: If you want to get familiar wth CPython source - read the [Python Dev Guide](https://devguide.python.org/), especially the [Internals section](https://devguide.python.org/internals/exploring/) - some of the links in there has in-depth explanations by some contributors to the language. I'd suggest keeping a copy of the source locally, and while you're getting familiar grep through the code if you're trying to find something. Also understand that some of the code is generated (you'll see stuff like `clinic` in the source). Also see: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

*But when I look through the os.py module source code, there is no function named openpty(). In fact, I am unable to find the source code for os.openpty() anywhere in the cpython codebase. What am I missing?*

You have to search for the string `os.openpty` in **all** files of the Python source distribution you should have available locally on your computer ( you will find more details and help in the comment to your question provided by wkl ).

This will give you for example with Linux grep `posixmodule.c:7176:os.openpty` as the result leading to:

```
#if defined(HAVE_OPENPTY) || defined(HAVE__GETPTY) || defined(HAVE_DEV_PTMX)
/*[clinic input]

os.openpty

Open a pseudo-terminal.

Return a tuple of (master_fd, slave_fd) containing open file descriptors
for both the master and slave ends.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
os_openpty_impl(PyObject *module)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=98841ce5ec9cef3c input=f3d99fd99e762907]*/
```

where you see that `os.openpty` is mapped to `os_openpty_impl`.